# What is the right way to build a UIButton composed of other UIViews?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to create a customized UIButton. It has a (changing) image, some informational text, and of course more standard things like a title and so on. I'm using interface builder and storyboards to do most of the design work in my app.

**What is the best practice to build a custom UIButton like this?**

I decided against subclassing and then just taking over the drawing since the button could be built from more standard elements.

Instead, I tried subclassing UIButton and building and adding subviews like UIImageView, UILabel, and so on. This seemed to work great with one exception, I wasn't sure when to position everything since the bounds are not set in awakeFromNib and initWithFrame is never called. Eventually, I added another method that my UIViewController called in viewDidAppear.

I then realized that perhaps I could just construct the button in the viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear in the UIViewController without subclassing, but I noticed again that bounds on the button were not yet available.

**So which is best:**

1. Subclassing and drawing everything
2. Subclassing and building by composition of other UIViews
3. Building the button in the outer view
4. Some other method...?

Also, it seems like everything in the framework conspires against manually laying out subviews when the parents are using autolayout, so I assume there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one separate UIView class and put all the buttons in it. 
then subclass that view to your view controller.

Like:

1)Create one view with your buttons and give that view as a class name to your custom .xib and also to the view.

i.e. I am creating one custom view with buttons named "MultipleChoiceLayout"
  - MultipleChoiceLayout.h
  - MultipleChoiceLayout.m
  - MultipleChoiceLayout.xib

I define MultipleChoiceLayout to File's owner and also the to the custom view.
[image]

2) add this custom view to your parent view

```
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MultiChoiceLayout" owner:self options:nil];

    MultiChoiceLayout *multipleChoiceLayout = [[MultipleChoiceLayout alloc] initWithArray:array];

   [ParentView addSubview:multipleChoiceLayout];
```

Look How I am Initializing the custom view in parent view.

I am passing the array to the "MultipleChoiceLayout" class and in multichoicelayout class I define self .

```
-(id)initWithArray:(NSArray*)array
   {
    self = [array objectAtIndex:0];
    if(self) {

     }
    return self;
}
```

- Now what happen is you are passing your custom view object from your parent to your custom view by passing the self from the parent (see above snippet). Now whenever you click on the button it will automatically call method that you define in the custom view. You dont have to maintain anything

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed your directions, but I can't call [ParentView addSubview:...] because I am using a storyboard to layout the parent view. So I tried combining your advice with this: https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142 and it got me pretty far except now my loaded xib doesn't properly replace the view.

Answer (score 1):

There are some common practices for building custom controls like that. In your case a subclass of `UIControl` would give you more flexibility than a standard `UIView` so you don't have to create custom gestures for the button interactions. Subclassing `UIButton` always leads to headaches from my experience.

As another answer shows, creating the control in a separate xib is also a good idea for reusability. It is generally more advisable to let your UIControl subclass setup it's components (UIImageView etc) than letting a view controller handle it. In this case the control will get messages like `initWithCoder:` if loading from a xib so you can properly setup the subviews.

As for using auto layout, if the rest of the app uses it, so should your custom control. Never mix autolayout and the manual setting of frames, things will break!

Hopefully this answers some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I tried combining some of your directions with BaZinga as well as a some hints from https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142. Unfortunately, even though now I can design my custom control in a xib and wire it all up in the corresponding h and m files, it doesn't display properly in the parent view. I'll put my code up.